# Mapping a Git commit to a Github PR?

Tags: git, github

If a Git commit is part of a Github pull request, how can I determine, given the commit hash, the pull request number?

In concrete terms, mapping `https://github.com/.../commit/704bf...` to `https://github.com/.../pull/123...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a 1-to-1 mapping of commits to PRs since a commit may be included in more than one PR. However, you can look into making use of the Github API to query the commits that belong to a particular PR and make your mapping that way.